# Customize postgres start command in default docker postgres image

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to change the start command of postgres to support SSL in the default docker image

**db.Docerfile**

```
FROM postgres:14.5-alpine

COPY ./.docker/dev/init-database.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

COPY ./.docker/dev/migrations/database_schema.tar ./

COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/server.key /var/lib/postgresql

COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/server.crt /var/lib/postgresql

COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/myCA.crt /var/lib/postgresql

COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/myCA.crl /var/lib/postgresql

COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/news_user.key ./

COPY ./.docker/dev/certs/out/news_user.crt ./

RUN chown 0:70 /var/lib/postgresql/server.key && chmod 640 /var/lib/postgresql/server.key

RUN chown 0:70 /var/lib/postgresql/server.crt && chmod 640 /var/lib/postgresql/server.crt

RUN chown 0:70 /var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt && chmod 640 /var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt

RUN chown 0:70 /var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl && chmod 640 /var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl

RUN chown 0:70 ./news_user.key && chmod 640 ./news_user.key

RUN chown 0:70 ./news_user.crt && chmod 640 ./news_user.crt

RUN chown postgres:postgres /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sh

EXPOSE 5432

CMD postgres -c ssl=on -c ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.crt -c ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.key -c ssl_ca_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt -c ssl_crl_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl


When I run this image, I get an error saying 
"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
news_database  | The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
news_database  | possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
news_database  | more information on how to properly start the server.
```

The default postgres image comes with a user named postgres so I tried adding a user postgres line before CMD

Now it gives me a new error saying

```
postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

Can someone kindly tell me how to fix this so that the postgres command works?

**UPDATE 1**

I am not running the dockerfile directly, I run it via a docker-compose.yml file since I have a python script that accesses the database in another container

**docker.compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  news_database:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./.docker/dev/db.Dockerfile
    container_name: news_database
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - news_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/55835081/5371505
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72213661/test-connection-to-postgres-with-ssl-with-the-command-line
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d 'hostaddr=$DATABASE_HOST user=$DATABASE_USER port=$DATABASE_PORT dbname=$DATABASE_NAME'"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  # Dont add a 'restart' policy to the app because we run it as a cronjob regardless of whether it succeeds or fails
  news_app:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594752/docker-compose-how-to-reference-files-in-other-directories
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: ./.docker/dev/app.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: news_app
    container_name: news_app
    depends_on:
      news_database:
        condition: service_healthy

volumes:
  news_db:
    driver: local
```

I run the above file with this command

```
docker compose -f ".docker/dev/docker-compose.yml" up -d --build news_database && docker compose -f ".docker/dev/docker-compose.yml" logs --follow
```

Comment: from [docker manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) If <dest> does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a regular file and the contents of <src> will be written at <dest>. So add / to COPY command and should works

Comment: @Lety i changed all my /var/lib/postgresql to /var/lib/postgresql/ and still get the error

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the docker run command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of problems with your Dockerfile.  First, I've stripped out a few bits to reduce the complexity to something I can reproduce locally, so I have:

```
FROM postgres:14.5-alpine

COPY ./certs/out/server.key /var/lib/postgresql
COPY ./certs/out/server.crt /var/lib/postgresql

RUN chown 0:70 /var/lib/postgresql/server.key && chmod 640 /var/lib/postgresql/server.key
RUN chown 0:70 /var/lib/postgresql/server.crt && chmod 640 /var/lib/postgresql/server.crt

EXPOSE 5432

CMD postgres -c ssl=on -c ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.crt -c ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.key -c ssl_ca_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt -c ssl_crl_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl
```

If we build a `pgtest` image from this Dockerfile and run it, we see:

```
$ docker build -t pgtest .
...
$ docker run --rm pgtest
"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.
```

What's going on here? It turns out this is caused by how you've written your `CMD` directive. You need to use the "exec style", which means passing in a JSON array rather than a string:

```
CMD ["postgres", \
  "-c", "ssl=on", \
  "-c", "ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.crt", \
  "-c", "ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.key"]
```

This is necessary because there's a check in the entrypoint script for
the image that looks like this:

```
if [ "$1" = 'postgres' ] && ! _pg_want_help "$@"; then
```

When you write:

```
CMD postgres -c ...
```

This wraps the command in a call to `sh -c`, so `$1` will be `sh`,
thus skipping the important database initialization logic. When we use
the exec format of the `CMD` statement, `$1` will be `postgres`, as
expected.

With that fix, the image runs correctly:

```
$ docker run --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret pgtest
.
.
.
PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2022-08-28 12:48:48.784 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 11.2.1 20220219, 64-bit
2022-08-28 12:48:48.784 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-08-28 12:48:48.784 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-08-28 12:48:48.786 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-08-28 12:48:48.789 UTC [48] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-28 12:48:48 UTC
2022-08-28 12:48:48.792 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: there s only one problem with the exec style, it does not substitute environment variables, basically i want to keep those certificate file names dynamic

Comment: I think this answer accurately identified the problem you  described in your question and provided a correct solution. If you have additional criteria consider asking a new question.

Comment: thank you for your assistance, you are right, this answer accurately solves the problem on this question, i have marked it as accepted, as for the other problem feel free to add an answer here if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502294/docker-postgres-file-illegal-option